# Нужны ли в отмеченных местах запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из-за неплотно закрытого окна(,) шторы еле заметно шелохнулись от ветра, тем самым(,) всего на мгновение(,) впуская тёплые лучи.
Заранее благодарю за ответы)

Comment: Почему предлагается закрыть вопрос?  Я не вижу в нем особых признаков домашнего задания. Автор показал нам, какая пунктуация вызывает у него затруднение. Я полагаю, что она у многих может вызывать затруднение. В ответе я предлагаю свою ВЕРСИЮ  решения, и возможно, кто-то думает иначе.  По крайей мере, мне пришлось  дополнительно использовать интонационные средства  анализа, и было бы  интересно, как можно выбрать и обосновать знаки, используя только правила.

Comment: Особых признаков нет, — что ни на есть типичное: без попыток самостоятельного решения.

Comment: 1. Пожалуйста, просмотрите последний десяток заданных тем. Вы видите среди них попытки самостоятельного решения (это касается и двух моих вопросов)?  Наверное, где-нибудь от нуля до одного. Так почему же вы хотите закрыть именно этот вопрос?  2. Запятые  здесь факультативные. У нас часто в этом случае отвечают так: можете ставить или не ставить.  Я не считаю, что это ответ.  Это общее решение, а нам нужно применить его для конкретного предложения. Сделать это не так просто, вот автор и обращается за помощью..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно предложить такое решение. Обстоятельственный оборот в начале предложения не обособляется, но обособляется уточняющее обстоятельство в составе деепричастного оборота:

***Из-за неплотно закрытого окна** // шторы еле заметно шелохнулись от ветра, тем самым, **всего на мгновение**, впуская тёплые лучи.*

Пояснение

1. Обособление обстоятельственного оборота «из-за неплотно закрытого окна» в начале предложения  является **факультативным**.  Произносительная пауза там в любом случае присутствует, но при обособлении оборот будет логически подчеркнут, а в этом **нет особой необходимости.**

Также надо учитывать структуру предложения: нам удобно разделить его **на  две (а не три) части** – основное предложение и обособленный деепричастный оборот.

2. Внутри деепричастного оборота  обособляем уточняющее обстоятельство «всего на мгновение». Здесь **вставочная интонация**, она не окажет значительного влияния на основную  (двухчастную) структуру предложения.  Но позиция оборота удобна для обособления; кроме того,  в этом случае уточнение **выделяется, подчеркивается**, что вполне вписывается в художественную задачу автора.